# Command line arguments output issue Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

starting java coder here. I've been fighting with this issue for a while now(couple of hours) and finally decided to ask for help.

Desired output is "random arg random arg random arg!" - so the point is to add "!" after final arg.

```
Public class Cmdtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.print(args[i]+ "!");
    }     
}
```

Been trying this, but it adds "!" after every arg instead of last one. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should check when your loop reaches the last element and add the arg at that element instead of doing it for every element

Comment: Hi Sammy and welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not a java expert but you should be able to simply copy the line inside your for-loop and paste it outside, so that you have `System.out.print(args[i]);` inside your loop and `System.out.print("!");` outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you want it to be displayed at the end, you can use conditional operator(`? :`) to check the last iteration, try this one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        System.out.print(i==args.length-1? args[i]+ "!":args[i]+ " ");          
}
```

Comment: read about it if you are interested  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html.

Comment: Thanks again, will read it. Still having little issues with spaces - now output is "Itisworking!", instead of "It is working!"

Comment: try it now updated, add space after`args[i]` like  `args[i]+  " "`

Comment: Works perfect, can't thank you enough. Have a nice one!

Comment: @Sammy you are welcome,  If an answer really solves your question, mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

do like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("!");
}
```

actually you were printing '!' in loop so it was being printed after every args

Comment: Use braces even if the loop only has one statement. Always.

Comment: Sure @nicomp Sir. :). updating

Comment: Now you have an extra `}` in there.

Comment: @killjoy You have the bestest SO user name. Hands down.